# Database design suggestions for a data scraping/warehouse application?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm looking into the database design for a data ware house kind of project which involves large number of inserts daily.The data archives will be further used to generate reports.I will have a list of user's (for example a user set of 2 million), for which I need to monitor daily social networking activities associated with them.

For example, let there be a set of 100 users say U1,U2,...,U100

I need to insert their daily status count into my database.

Consider the total status count obtained for a user U1 for period June 30 - July 6, is as follows

```
June 30 - 99
July 1 - 100
July 2 - 102
July 3 - 102
July 4 - 105
July 5 - 105
July 6 - 107
```

The database should keep daily status count of each users ,like

For user U1,

```
July 1- 1 (100-99)
July 2- 2 (102-100) 
July 3- 0 (102-102) 
July 4- 3 (105-102) 
July 5- 0 (105-105) 
July 6- 2 (107-105)
```

Similarly the database should hold archived details of the full set of user's.

And on a later phase , I envision to take aggregate reports out of these data like total points scored on each day,week,month,etc; and to compare it with older data.

I need to start things from the scratch.I am experienced with PHP as a server side script and MySQL. I am confused on the database side? Since I need to process about a million insertion daily,what all things should be taken care of?

I am confused on how to to design a MySQL database in this regard ? On which storage engine to be used and design patterns to be followed keeping in my mind the data could later used effectively with aggregate functions.

Currently I envision the DB design with one table storing all the user id's with a foreign key and separate status count table for each day.Does lot of table's could create some overhead?

Does **MySQL** fits my requirement? 2 million or more DB operations are done every day. How the server and other things are to be considered in this case.

1) The database should handle concurrent inserts, which should enable 1-2 million inserts per day.

Before inserting I suggest to calculate daily status count,i.e the difference today's count with yesterday's.

2) on a later phase, the archives data (collected over past days) is used as a data warehouse and aggregation tasks are to be performed on it.

Comments:

I have read MyISAM is the best choice for data warehousing projects and at the same time heard INNODB excels in many ways. Many have suggested on proper tuning to get it done, I would like to get thoughts on that as well.

Comment: I would recommend when you `create table` select an appropriate `partition by`.

Comment: @Charlesliam So are you suggesting a single big table with user id foreign key reference with partition? Hope it should be a date wise partition and I don't know if large table could affect speed.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a data warehouse, you don't have to worry about normalization.  You're inserting rows and reading rows.

I'd just have one table like this.

```
Status Count
------------
User id
Date
Count
```

The primary (clustering) key would be (User id, Date).  Another unique index would be (Date, User id).

As far as whether or not MySQL can handle this data warehouse, that depends on the hardware that MySQL is running on.

Since you don't need referential integrity, I'd use MyISAM as the engine.

Comment: Thanx a lot for this.But I didn't get why you suggested a clustering index with User id, Date and another unique index (Date, User id) ? On index I believe this could help in managing duplicate entries to the table. I have read MyISAM has got some demerits over INNODB and could day-wise partition could be applied to this.

Comment: What about using partitioning in this case? I don't have any practical experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

As for table design, a dimensional model with a star schema is usually a good choice for a datamart where there are mostly inserts and reads.  I see two different granularities for the status data, one for status per day and one for status per user, so I would recommend tables similar to:

```
user_status_fact(user_dimension_id int, lifetime_status int)

daily_status_fact (user_dimension_id int, calendar_dimension_id int, daily_status int)

user_dimension(user_dimension_id, user_id, name, ...)

calendar_dimension(calendar_dimension_id, calendar_date, day_of_week, etc..)
```

You might also consider having the most detailed data available even though you don't have a current requirement for it as it may make it easier to build aggregates in the future:

```
status_fact (user_dimension_id int, calendar_dimension_id int, hour_dimension_id,  status_dimension_id, status_count int DEFAULT 1)

hour_dimension(hour_dimension_id, hour_of_day_24, hour_of_day_12, ...)

status_dimension(status_dimension_id, status_description string, ...)
```

If you aren't familiar with the dimensional model, I would recommend the book data warehouse toolkit by Kimball.

I would also recommend MyISAM since you don't need the transactional integrity provided by InnoDB when dealing with a read-mostly warehouse.

I would question whether you want to do concurrent inserts into a production database though.  Often in a warehouse environment this data would get batched over time and inserted in bulk and perhaps go through a promotion process.

As for scalability, mysql can certainly handle 2M write operations per day on modest hardware. I'm inserting 500K+ rows/day (batched hourly) on a cloud based server with 8GB of ram running apache + php + mysql and the inserts aren't really noticeable to the php users hitting the same db.

I'm assuming you will get one new row per user per day inserted (not 2M rows a day as some users will have more than one status).  You should look at how many new rows per day you expect that to created.  When you get to a large number of rows you might have to consider partitioning, sharding and other performance tricks.  There are many books out there that can help you with that.  Or you could also consider moving to an analytics db such as Amazon Red Shift.

Comment: Ideally for performance reasons, you wouldn't want a high transaction count OLTP database on the same server as the OLAP (Data Warehouse). Typically, the data is processed in batches, isn't normalized and is staged in tables already processed for reporting purposes, so plan on a two stage process... OLTP, then processing/storing to OLAP.

Comment: I would question whether you want to do concurrent inserts into a production database though//
I envision to scrap the content and to store date in a data ware house kind of database.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a fact table for each user status for each day. This fact table would connect to a date dimension via a date_key and to a user dimension via a user_key. The primary key for the fact table should be a surrogate key = status_key.

So, your fact table now has four fields: status_key, date_key, user_key, status.

Once the dimension and fact tables have been loaded, then do the processing and aggregating.

Edit: I assumed you knew something about datamarts and star schemas. Here is a simple star schema to base your design on.
[image]

This design will store any user's status for a given day. (If the user status can change during the day, just add a time dimension).

This design will work on MySQL or SQL Server. You will have to manage a million inserts per day, don't bog it down with comparisons to previous data points. You can do that with the datamart (star schema) after it's loaded - that's what it's for - analysis and aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

If there are large number of DML operation and selecting records from database MYISAM engine would be prefer. INNODB is mainly use for TCL and referential integrity.You can also specify engine at table level.

If you need to generate the report then also MYISAM engine work faster than INNODB.See which table or data you need for your report.

Remember that if you generate reports from MYSQL database processing on millions of data using PHP programming could create a problem.You may encounter 500 or 501 error frequently.

So report generation view point MYISAM engine for required table will be useful.

You can also store data in multiple table to prevent overhead otherwise there is a chance for DB table crash.

Comment: @shah Akhtar What about multiple tables,should I consider datatbases to be created in weekly or monthly order.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a schema that will keep a single count per user per day. Very simple. You should create a single table which is DAY, USER_ID, and STATUS_COUNT.

Create an index on DAY and USER_ID together, and if possible keep the data in the table sorted by DAY and USER_ID also. This will give you very fast access to the data, as long as you are querying it by day ranges for any (or all) users.

For example:

```
select * from table where DAY = X and USER_ID in (Y, Z);
```

would be very fast because the data is ordered on disk sequentially by day, then by user_id, so there are very few seeks to satisfy the query.

On the other hand, if you are more interested in finding a particular user's activity for a range of days:

```
select * from table where USER_ID = X and DAY between Y and Z;
```

then the previous method is less optimal because finding the data will require many seeks instead of a sequential scan. Index first by USER_ID, then DAY, and keep the data sorted in that order; this will require more maintenance though, as the table would need to be re-sorted often. Again, it depends on your use case, and how fast you want your queries against the table to respond.

I don't use MySQL extensively, but I believe MyISAM is faster for inserts at the expense of transaction isolation. This should not be a problem for the system you're describing.

Also, 2MM records per day should be child's play (only 23 inserts / second) if you're using decent hardware. Especially if you can batch load the records using mysqlimport. If that's not possible, 23 inserts/second should still be very doable.

I would not do the computation of the delta from the previous day in the insertion of the current day however. There is an analytic function called LAG() that will do that for you very handily (http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/), not to mention it doesn't seem to serve any practical purpose at the detail level.

With this detail data, you can aggregate it any way you'd like, truncating the DAY column down to WEEK or MONTH, but be careful how you build aggregates. You're talking about over 7 billion records per year, and re-building aggregates over so many rows can be very costly, especially on a single database. You might consider doing aggregation processing using Hadoop (I'd recommend Spark over plain old Map/Reduce also, its far more powerful). This will alleviate any computation burden from your database server (which can't easily scale to multiple servers) and allow it to do its job of recording and storing new data.

You should consider partitioning your table as well. Some purposes of partitioning tables are to distribute query load, ease archival of data, and possibly increase insert performance. I would consider partitioning along the month boundary for an application such as you've described.